# How to filter text in MatLab cell?

Tags: matlab

I’m currently importing a text file to a cell array using textscan. Each word has its own cell and I want to delete every word that is not “true” or “false”. The text file is a bunch of words. What should I do?

Comment: `c = c( ismember( c, {'true', 'false'} ) );`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following function strcmp in Matlab. You can do something like `strcmp(c,'true')`. If that evaluates to 1 you can go ahead and delete it